# How to navigate from one page to another in angular2

Tags: angular2-routing

I am new to angular2. How to navigate from one page to another in angular2?. I am using router-outlets for that. It just redirects between one component to another but i want to redirect from home page to another when i click on dropdown items.Do i need to use page-router-outlets for that? If so how to use that and how to install nativescript and all. Thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: Can you add some examples, what you are trying to achieve, Do read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), also look into [Router documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router) on Angular official docs, Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I am using app.route.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home' ,  component: HomeComponent,pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'about',  component: AboutComponent }
];
```

In app.component.html i have

```
<ul>
<li id="home"><a [routerLink]="['/home']" >Home</a> </li>
<li id="about"><a  [routerLink]="['/about']" >About</a></li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In app.module.ts I have configured the router.
When i click on home hyperlink it will route to app.component.html page only. Its not redirecting to another page and app.component.html is always shown on the top of the page every single time I go to a new page. 
How to route to new page without showing the app.component.html in the new page.